# Tachometer doesnt show correct RPM sometimes

Tags: honda, rpm

On my Honda CBF 150cc , the Tachometer shows RPM correctly when i'm at a constant speed. But some times when i slow down and accelerate the RPM Needle moves unexpectedly. (say to 0 even i'm at a reasonable speed and suddenly goes way too high where i'm just starting to accelerate). Any ideas why this is happening ?

> Update:Its Analogue i think(Traditional one with the Needle and
>   Numbers)

This update was proposed by an anonymous user so I am not sure if it was from the OP.

Comment: Is it an aftermarket tacho? And is it digital or analogue?

Comment: By analog I think he is referring to if there is a cable attached to the back of the gauge (middle of the dial) or does it just have wires (digital signal).

Comment: I have a needle with numbers tacho on my bike but its digital so we cant be sure if the edit is based on that observation alone

Comment: It seems that the question implied is why would my tachometer give spurious readings and what might be done to fix it.